# Keyword 'BuiltIn.Exit For Loop If' expected 1 argument, got 2

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am new learner of RobotFramework, I tried to run this code, but this error shows: Keyword 'BuiltIn.Exit For Loop If' expected 1 argument, got 2. Thank you in advance!

```
Select the Card
[arguments]     ${cardName}
${elements} =   Get WebElements   css:.card-title
${index}=   Set Variable    1
 FOR     ${element}  IN  @{elements}
   Exit For Loop If      '${cardName}' ==  '${element.text}'
   ${index}=   Evaluate    ${index} + 1
 END
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two spaces after `==`. Robot uses two or more spaces as argument separators so it sees `'${cardName}' ==` as one argument and `'${element.text}'` as a second argument.

The solution is to make sure the entire expression doesn't have any sequences of two or more spaces.

```
Exit For Loop If      '${cardName}' == '${element.text}'
```